# How to create database for big amount of file?

Tags: mysql, database, file

everyone

I'm building a photo forum website like 500px, I met some problem when trying to construct the database for those images. Do I need to create a new table for each photo the user updated where there are photo id, photo "likes", photo description, photo comments, photo update time, etc? Would it make my server explode to create too much tables in mysql? Or, what's the best practice to store all those informations in database except image itself(I would store them in a directory)? Thanks!

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow: there's no "right answer" to this question; only opinions. Also, this is super-broad, as there are so many ways to model a database, so many database types (key/value, column-family, relational, document, graph), etc. Based on your question though, I think it would be wise for you to study up a bit on relational database modeling (since you're already leaning toward a relational database) to gain a better understanding of the use of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just one table `photos`. And for each photo you should add a new record to this table. I'd suggest you to read more theory on database design. Then there will be no reason to ask such questions.

Edit: For comments you should create another table with fields: `id`, `user_id`, `photo_id`, `comment`, `created_at` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to create a new table for each user? If you've got one database table with proper index you should be fine and if the table gets bigger over time, you can just do sharding and put it on multiple servers.